# View changed files in a git stash

Tags: git

Stash command is really useful when you switch to new directory without carrying the working changes. But, is there anyway to see the list of changed files in a particular stash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the latest stash:

`git stash show --name-only`

For a specific stash:

`git stash show --name-only <stash>`

Comment: This is generally the right answer (and I'm upvoting it), but one should be aware that this compares the stashed work-directory commit against its parent commit, ignoring the stashed index commit.  There's no `stash` sub-command to view the index commit itself.  You can "peek inside" the two (or three) stash commits with "git show" or viewers like `gitk`, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `gitk --all` and view stash's diffs in GUI

Comment: `gitk` is a GUI for git, you can view stashes diffs in it.